# Web scraping from js website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape the form data from the https://www.investing.com/commodities/gold-historical-data,
but this form generate by js. I tried to imacros to see the action and got this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:widgetFieldDateRange
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:20
    TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:13
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:applyBtn
```

Can anyone tell me how to change this to python code which I can use in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a POST request (Ajax).

### How did I find that?

Well, I inspected the **XHR from the Network section**

[image: investing_ajax_post]

The POST data you need is (replace with the dates you want):

```
curr_id=8830
smlID=300004
st_date=08/09/2017
end_date=08/21/2017
interval_sec=Daily
sort_col=date
sort_ord=DESC
action=historical_data
```

The IDs from the aobe POST data, probably are for this market only(gold-historical-data), so for others inspect the network again and see POST data everytime.

## How do you implement this in Python?

You need a module called `requests`.

Specifically, read [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: hi, I want to get a certain period time data, on the website you need to click the start time and end time. My problem is that I don't know how to finish this step in selenium cause I cannot find the date DOM to finish click action.

Comment: You cannot achieve a POST request with selenium. I highly suggest  using the module  requests for this one. Please read more about server requests (GET, POST etc..) to understand what is going on.